# Write with two different languages

Tags: babel, languages, arabic

I am writing an article in English but I need some examples to be writen with Arabic language like this :

> For example, the Arabic words دارس (student) and مدرس (teacher) share the same Arabic root.

What shold I do?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution :

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\maketitle
\setcode{utf8}
\vocalize %for the vowel mark it can be also \novocalize \fullvocalize
\transtrue %transliteration convention
\arabtrue

....
```